# Ubuntu 12.04, Php5-fpm, Apache2, Postfix: impossible to send a mail with PHP

Tags: apache2, php, email, webserver, postfix

### Resources I followed

I followed several howtos and questions on askubuntu:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix
- [How to configure apache / php / postfix website emails when using vhosts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200835/how-to-configure-apache-php-postfix-website-emails-when-using-vhosts)
- [Sending mails with PHP, LAMPP and PostFix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88117/sending-mails-with-php-lampp-and-postfix)

And it does not fix my issue.

### Configuration

- This is a Kimsufi server from OVH, quad core with 2 Gb of memory
- I just installed the basic Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server
- I then installed apache2, php-fpm, mysql, two custom cron scripts for backup
- I use it for a multisite Wordpress, where I manage my blog and blogs of family and friends, plus a few customers

### Issue

Php-fpm cannot send email, even after following official community documention on Ubuntu wiki, and other tips and tricks I find.

For PHP, it seems that the email is sent, but the test mail never come in my inbox...

What do I miss ? Is there a very simple solution ?

By the way, when this will be fixed, I would be happy to write a full howto about that.

### /var/log/mail.log

http://pastebin.com/8j7y1upw

Comment: Please provide mail-related logs (`/var/log/mail.*`).

Comment: done, via pastebin. the log are after installing php-mail and restarting php-fpm and apache2.

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/postfix/master.cf` and `cat /etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: At the moment, I am looking at other way than Postfix !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was unable to make Postfix working, I finally used Exim4.

At the beginning, test emails with php worked out of the box, except for emails sent by Wordpress. Exim4 gave this message : Unrouteable address.

### The solution

I made a mistake in the configuration. Instead of giving the name of the machine (ns3098501.ip-94-23-10.eu) I gave "libre-factory.com", which is the name I use for the Wordpress network.

Once I did a new configuration with the good name, it worked.

Please notice that the path to sendmail is set to default "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i" and that it works well.